# How to include LookAt tag from KML to geopandas

Tags: python, kml, geopandas

I am trying to include the `LookAt` tags from a KML file in a geopandas Dataframe.  Is there a way to include this info when reading a KML file?

```
import geopandas as gpd

# enable KML support
import fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw'
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

kml_data = gpd.read_file(kml_file, driver="KML")
print(kml_data)
```

outputs:

```
                 Name Description                                  geometry
0  Untitled Placemark              POINT Z (-111.67105 40.73901 1878.41524)
1  Untitled Placemark              POINT Z (-111.67734 40.74231 1864.92033)
```

Here is the KML file I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Point Heading Test</name>
    <gx:CascadingStyle kml:id="__managed_style_2E6516847120780A15BB">
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.2</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://earth.google.com/earth/rpc/cc/icon?color=1976d2&amp;id=2000&amp;scale=4</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="64" y="128" xunits="pixels" yunits="insetPixels"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
            </LabelStyle>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff2dc0fb</color>
                <width>6</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>40ffffff</color>
            </PolyStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <displayMode>hide</displayMode>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
    </gx:CascadingStyle>
    <gx:CascadingStyle kml:id="__managed_style_11E9292D0420780A15BB">
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://earth.google.com/earth/rpc/cc/icon?color=1976d2&amp;id=2000&amp;scale=4</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="64" y="128" xunits="pixels" yunits="insetPixels"/>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
            </LabelStyle>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff2dc0fb</color>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>40ffffff</color>
            </PolyStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <displayMode>hide</displayMode>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
    </gx:CascadingStyle>
    <StyleMap id="__managed_style_0340E958DE20780A15BB">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#__managed_style_11E9292D0420780A15BB</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#__managed_style_2E6516847120780A15BB</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark id="006539C7DA20780A15BB">
        <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-111.6665613333234</longitude>
            <latitude>40.73210784610954</latitude>
            <altitude>1978.530698138617</altitude>
            <heading>270</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <gx:fovy>35.00001091304519</gx:fovy>
            <range>2861.119629179011</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#__managed_style_0340E958DE20780A15BB</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-111.6710488014016,40.73900677470505,1878.415244918022</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="0BD42C630E20780A65DE">
        <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-111.6665613337695</longitude>
            <latitude>40.73210784621531</latitude>
            <altitude>1978.53130180304</altitude>
            <heading>300</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <gx:fovy>35.00001091304519</gx:fovy>
            <range>2861.119072916627</range>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#__managed_style_0340E958DE20780A15BB</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-111.6775229090924,40.74237607785169,1864.920326145229</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Not possible without parsing the KML manually, even with the more advanced "LIBKML" driver (`fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'`). The underlying OGR library can write `LookAt` elements at the document level (using "LIBKML"), but not the placemark level and can't read them at all.

Comment: Well, that is a bummer. Thanks for the quick answer @user2856. Do you have any recommendations for reading it manually?  Or is it best to just read it as XML at that point?

Comment: Yes I was thinking reading the xml. Looks like there's some work happening in the fastkml library to support LookAt but it's not ready yet.